# Structure Issue after copying bucket items from one instance to another instance

Tags: buckets

The existing Sitecore instance has bucket items with default structure 'yyyy/MM/dd/HH/mm'. I've tried to copy bucket items into new Sitecore instance. But the new instance structure looks flat. I can see all structure in new instance but not in tree format. The functionality is working fine.

Please suggest to make the content tree structure in the new instance.

**Old instance**

[image]

**New Instance**

[image]

Comment: How did you copied them from one instance to another?

Comment: Created a package using Package Designer and imported using Installation Wizard option.

Comment: In old and new instance what is this setting BucketConfiguration.BucketFolderPath set to? Can be found in ShowConfig.aspx. Are they the same? Do you have on old instance custom rules implemented for your template and buckets and you just forgotten to deploy it to new instance? See further info info -> https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/search_and_item_buckets/custom_bucket_structures

Comment: BucketConfiguration.BucketFolderPath is same in both instances (<setting name="BucketConfiguration.BucketFolderPath" value="yyyy\/MM\/dd\/HH\/mm"/>). There is no custom rule implemented.

Comment: Venkat, I am running into similar issue. Have you find any solution? I have tried above suggestions but no luck. Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three options.

**1. Sync your bucket again**

1. Navigate to your bucket root
2. Click `Sync` button in `CONFIGURE` section

[image]

If the first step will not work you have to check if both instances have the same bucket path settings

**2. Copy Item Buckets Settings**

1. Find item: `/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Item Buckets Settings`
2. Compare `Rules for Resolving the Bucket Folder Path` field on two instances. Settings there should be the same

[image]

**3. Custom Bucket Rules**

There is also a third option. If you use some custom bucket rules (Sitecore setting `BucketConfiguration.DynamicBucketFolderPath`) make sure they are deployed on both instances.

Comment: Thanks Peter for details. I verified above three options, both instances look same. Sitecore.Buckets.config file also same in both instances. It seems there is a problem with configuration somewhere. I'll check.

Comment: I just slightly edited Alan's answer :) Credit goes to him :)